# Is __DEV__ defined on production?

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native app and it's crashing only in production (not local), I think because of `__DEV__`. Is `__DEV__` defined in production?

Comment: It's not defined in production.

Comment: Could you post that part of your code, which tries to access `__DEV__`?

Comment: @BenClayton do you have documentation for that? I mean, what is the point of `__DEV__` being set if it's not defined in production, so you can't use it?

Comment: It's how you can tell that the app is in development mode

Comment: `if (__DEV__) { } else {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some investigation myself, `__DEV__` is set to `true` when running on an iOS or Android simulator.